# Are you a Magento Ninja? (Just for fun)

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

You really do deserve a quick break, you know? So, we hope that this post is deemed appropriate...

We’re big fans of Magento and we’ve launched a fun game that’ll test your Magento and ecommerce skills which has been getting a great response from people across the Magneto community.

I thought it would be great if you guys could give it a go and let us know what you think.

So, are you a [Magento Ninja](http://www.absolute-design.co.uk/services/magento-ecommerce-development/magento-ninja/app/index.html)?

Comment: Hm, pretty straightforward imho. Would have loved something like the Dev.-Certification. Nice idea, though.

Comment: Nice site, was fun to play

Comment: Didn't realize it requires a minimum screen height at first. Otherwise, it's nice, but there are some debatable questions. For example, the one about Magento's built-in search functionality - EE's Solr integration is pretty solid. Sure, Solr itself is a 3rd party tool, but Magento has a built-in integration for it.

Comment: Nice and fun - and I learn some tips

Comment: Its fun but very basic. I would not exactly call some one a gold ninja, based on those 20 questions.

Comment: Nicely made! :)