# Meta website is starting to lose its purpose.

Tags: discussion

The meta website associated to each stackexchange website is there to discuss things about the main website.
I see that this meta website is starting to turn into something else.
I admit I contributed to this "state" with these questions:

- [Funny / Useless / Horrible code from Magento Extensions](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/288/146)
- [Let's make this fun(-ish)](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/240/146)
- [Funny / Useless / Horrible code from Magento Extensions](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/288/146)

In my defense, I tried to make it a little funnier for all of us. But now I realize my mistake and I will stop.
But lately I've seen some questions that should not be here that seams to me like hidden promotion (I don't want to say spam).

- https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/703/146
- [Who would like to participate in developing and maintaing a Blog Overflow Community Blog for Magento StackExchange](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/659/146)
- [Are you a Magento Ninja? (Just for fun)](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/580/146)
- [Teaching magento flow](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/729/146)

My opinion is that we should stop posting or migrating this kind of questions in here.
Otherwise we risk turning this meta into a showcase / self promotion / sales channel.

Like I said, this is my opinion. I would love to see other views on this topic.

Comment: I agree about the promotion stuff. But still I love and thus would not ban a bit of general/overall fun (referring to the funny/useless/horrible code questions) here :)

Comment: Marius, in general I'm in favor of your suggestion.  The only caveat I'd add was #2 (which I submitted) which I believe was, at the time submitted, specifically relevant to a StackExchange Meta topic on the blogs being added when sites exited Beta.  It seems inevitable that SE is going to revisit features that are provided to full community sites and I feel that Meta is the appropriate place for those discussions & seeking volunteers for SE-related activities.  Blatant promotion of services doesn't have a place, though I kind of share your & Anna's perspective on injecting SOME levity here :D

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta "Meta Magento Stack Exchange is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Magento Stack Exchange rather than discussing the Magento e-Commerce platform itself. It is separated from the main Q&A to reduce noise there while providing a legitimate space for people to ask how and why this site works the way it does. Meta is for...

...Magento Stack Exchange users to communicate with each other about Magento Stack Exchange (asking questions about how the websites work, or about policies and community decisions)

Answer (score 4):

Hm, I'm in favor. Makes it easier to get through the content posted here.

The rest can be posted on [community.magento.com](http://community.magento.com). They have several misc. channels.

Answer (score 2):

I think we can remove if there are such question like spam but sometimes we dont need answer but its about discussion on some important topic and need input from experts on meta.

I am referring here question [Teaching magento flow](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/729/29175). Here users will come to know the proper way of learning magento and proper way to explain the magento system.

I agree that few questions are spams but not all. This is my personal views because we could post question in magento or meta if question is related to magento.